# how to detect the outer frame of an object

Tags: opencv, edge-detection, object-detection, android

I am using OpenCV4Android version 3.1.0 and I want the Android camera to be able to detect a card e.g: credit-card, customer's card or etc. To implement such functionalitey using OpenCV i tried to do it using Edge-Detection function, but 
as you see in the picture below, Edge-Detection detects all the edges in the frame, while what I am looking for is to detect the only the outer frame of the card.

I tried also Object-Detection "contour-detection" function, and as you see in the picture below, it did not detect the outer frame of the card.

please let me know what is the optimal solution or function i should use to be able to detect only the outer frame of any given card

**Edge-Detection**:
[image]

**Shape"contour" Detection**:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of edges that are found by edge detection is related to the thresholds you set (or that are set by default). Try manipulating with these thresholds to see if you get better results. You can also try gradient function, where you will get the "strength" of the edge instead of just binary "presence" of the edge. This will show you, that not all edges are equal.

Comment: thanks..would you please tell me how to use the gradient function you mentioned with canny edge-detector?

Comment: You can use e.g Sobel function, which calculates image derivatives. More details can be found in [link](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gacea54f142e81b6758cb6f375ce782c8d) or [link](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d2/d2c/tutorial_sobel_derivatives.html)